# A child flips 7 fair coins.Find the probability that atleast two heads occur,given that atleast three tails occur.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A child flips 7 fair coins.Find the probability that atleast two heads occur,given that atleast three tails occur.

---

I know this question is of conditional probability.Let event $A=$atleast two heads occur,$B=$atleast three tails occur.$A\cap B=$atleast two heads and atleast three tails occur.

$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

$A=\left\{H,H,X,X,X,X,X\right\},B=\left\{T,T,T,X,X,X,X\right\}$
$A\cap B=\left\{H,H,T,T,T,X,X\right\}$,here $H$ is for head,$T$ is for tail and $X$ is for head or tail

P(H)=$\frac{1}{2},P(T)=\frac{1}{2},P(X)=1$.

Then i am stuck.Please help me to get the answer.

Comment: You can get the vertical bar for conditional probabilities with proper spacing using `\mid`, as in `P(A\mid B)`, which produces $P(A\mid B)$. Also, you can get displayed equations, which are less cramped than inline equations, using double dollar signs instead of single dollar signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 3 possible combinations of (T,H): $(3,4), (4,3), 5,2)$. Define H:'success'. In the fist case you need $\binom{7}{4}p^4 (1-p)^3$. This is called Binomial probability. Remaining cases are similar. You can sum the probabilities because events are mutually exclusive.