# A child flips 7 fair coins. Find the probability that at least two heads occur, given that at least three tails occur.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Question: A child flips 7 fair coins. There are relatively prime positive integers m and n so that $\frac{m}{n}$  is the probability that at least two heads occur, given that at least three tails occur. Find (m + n).

From the language of the question I figured out that it is asking the conditional probability for the events:

1.Occurrence of at least 2 heads=event A

2. Occurrence of at least 3 tails=event B ie. $$P(E)=\frac{P(A and B)}{P(B)}$$

My approach:

In order to find $P(B)$, I found the the probability that no tails occur ($\frac{1}{2^{7}}$), only one tail occurs ($\frac{7}{2^{7}}$) and only two tail occurs ($\frac{\binom{7}{2}}{2^{7}}$), adding them up and subtracting from 1 I obtained,$$P(B)=1-\frac{29}{2^{7}}$$
Now to find $P(AandB)$ I chose any 5 tosses from the 7 available ones in $\binom{7}{5}$ ways and arrangen 3 tails and 2 heads in $\frac{5!}{2!3!}$ ways, now it doesn't matter what occurs on the remaining two places(as the initial condition has been satisfied), so it's probability should be $$\binom{7}{5}\frac{5!}{3!2!}\frac{1}{2^{5}}$$ but this value comes out to be greater than 1, I am unable to find out the error in my assumptions and calculations, please help.

I know this question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461197/a-child-flips-7-fair-coins-find-the-probability-that-atleast-two-heads-occur-giv), but I want to clarify where I have gone wrong or misjudged.

Comment: First thing is, you need to take the probabilities of all the $7$ places, so that the second probability should have $\frac1{2^7}$ instead of $\frac1{2^5}$. However, even in that case, you are counting arrangements like $(T,T,H,T,H,H,T)$ multiple times in $\binom75\frac{5!}{3!2!}$, once for the $5$ places $(T,T,H,T,H,\_,\_)$, once for the $5$ places $(T,\_,H,T,H,\_,T)$ and so on. Valid cases like these are severely overcounted. You might need to count by taking the complement case and using the principle of inclusion exclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea and computation for $\mathbb{P}(B)$ are correct. Your idea for $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$ is incorrect, as it does matter what the other two values in your sequence are. As @Fawkes4494d3 just correctly pointed out, you count events multiple times when you do it this way. For a proper solution, think about the events in which you have both 2 or more heads and 3 or more tails. The only events that satisfy this combination are 3,4 or 5 tails. So think about how you can compute the probability on these events.